# How can I resolve exception: Error executing child request for ChartImg.axd

Tags: .net, asp.net, exception, charts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [.NET 3.5 chart controls exception: Error executing child request for ChartImg.axd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302820/net-3-5-chart-controls-exception-error-executing-child-request-for-chartimg-ax)

I'm using the Chart Controls for Mircosoft .NET Framerwork. Most of the time they work perfectly. However, if I leave a page for longer than 20-30 mins and then try to refresh the page, I get an error saying:

> Error executing child request for ChartImg.axd. 
>   Exception Details: System.Web.HttpException: Error executing child request for ChartImg.axd.

If I update the page using an AJAX update panel I get the following error:

> Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerServerErrorException: Error executing child request for ChartImg.axd

It seems that the chart handler stops after a period of inactivity. Most of the webpages I've looked at for this error are for situations when this error is displayed all the time. In my case it is only displayed after a period of inactivity.
Can someone provide a better explanation of what is happening and suggest a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer this :

[.NET 3.5 chart controls exception: Error executing child request for ChartImg.axd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302820/net-3-5-chart-controls-exception-error-executing-child-request-for-chartimg-axd)