# Error executing child request for ChartImg.axd. This is not a duplicate

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, charts

I have tried all solutions on this thread:
[.NET 3.5 chart controls exception: Error executing child request for ChartImg.axd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/302820/net-3-5-chart-controls-exception-error-executing-child-request-for-chartimg-ax)

I added the

```
<add
    path="ChartImg.axd" 
    verb="GET,HEAD" 
    type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" 
    validate="false" />
```

code to the `httpHandlers` section but it still doesn't work.

I have also added:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />
</appSettings>

<httpHandlers>
...
    <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
...
</httpHandlers>

<handlers>
...
    <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />

...
</handlers>
```

But after fighting for a while to place those tags in the correct places in the config file i get the same error.

Here is my config file currently:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>

  <appSettings>
    <add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\TempImageFiles\;" />
  </appSettings>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>

      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />

    </httpHandlers>

    <!--<pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="artem" namespace="Artem.Google.UI" assembly="Artem.Google"/>
      </controls>
    </pages>-->
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5">

      <assemblies> 
        <add assembly="System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>  

      </assemblies>

    </compilation>

    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Ive been stuck on this for two hours not able to get anything working. 
I am using .net framework 4.5

Answer (score 8):

Here was my situation:

- upgraded from 3.5 to 4.0
- it worked when compiled locally on my machine (64-bit Win7)
- Did NOT work when published to a Win2003 server

I was simply missing this:

```
<system.web><httpHandlers>
  <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
    validate="false" />
</httpHandlers></system.web>
```

Answer (score 6):

I managed to solve the problem (I am using DotNetNuke and I had the error "Error executing child request for ChartImg.axd.")

I added the following lines to my web.config file

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    ...
    <handlers>
      ...
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST"
        path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
    <validation validateIntegratedModeConfiguration="false" />
  </system.webServer>
  <system.web>
    <httpHandlers>
      <add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35"
        validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
    ...
  </system.web>

</configuration>
```

In DotNetNuke, if you want to update the config file from the module during the installation, follow [this post](http://www.dnnsoftware.com/forums/forumid/205/threadid/432396/scope/posts).

Answer (score 2):

To anyone else with this problem having not being able to fix it.

1. I went here:
   http://forums.asp.net/t/1843074.aspx/1
2. I copied and pasted this this code into their appropriate sections in the the web.config file.
3. I then recieved this error message from IIS 8 on running of the page with the chart control:

   HTTP Error 500.23 - Internal Server Error
   An ASP.NET setting has been detected that does not apply in Integrated managed pipeline mode.
4. The message also contains suggestions:

> Things you can try: Migrate the configuration to the
>   system.webServer/handlers section. You can do so manually or by using
>   AppCmd from the command line. For example, from the IIS Express
>   install directory, run appcmd migrate config "Default Web Site/".
>   Using AppCmd to migrate your application will enable it to work in
>   Integrated mode. It will continue to work in Classic mode and on
>   previous versions of IIS. If you are certain that it is OK to ignore
>   this error, it can be disabled by setting
>   system.webServer/validation@validateIntegratedModeConfiguration to
>   false. Alternatively, switch the application to a Classic mode
>   application pool. For example, from the IIS Express install directory,
>   run appcmd set app "Default Web Site/"
>   /applicationPool:"Clr4ClassicAppPool". Only do this if you are unable
>   to migrate your application.

One of the suggestion were to:

> switch the application to a Classic mode application pool. For
>   example, from the IIS Express install directory, run appcmd set app
>   "Default Web Site/" /applicationPool:"Clr4ClassicAppPool". Only do
>   this if you are unable to migrate your application.

So I google it and I went here:

[How to switch IIS Developer Express to "Classic Mode"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3748466/how-to-switch-iis-developer-express-to-classic-mode)

The best solution to change to classic mode was this:

> Using appcmd is not needed, it is best to change this in the project's
>   settings:
>
> Click on the web project in the solution explorer Press F4 to get the
>   properties page to show up (not the properties sheet, but the simpler
>   properties window where you set up general things) Look for 'Managed
>   Pipeline Mode', change this to 'Classic'

Now the Chart control works. If anyone has a better solution (e.g the other solutions suggestions in the error which I do not understand) feel free to answer with a clearer description of those suggetsions.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following attributes in the root asp:chart tag

```
ImageLocation="~/images/temp/ChartPic_#SEQ(300,3)" ImageStorageMode="UseImageLocation"
```

remove all configurations in web.config. With the above changes you are going to handle to where to save the chart image not the chart api.

Answer (score 1):

The solution that had worked for me is the one posted [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1843074.aspx)

```
<system.web>
//comment this in local IIS7, on host uncomment
<httpHandlers>
<add path="ChartImg.axd" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" validate="false" />
    </httpHandlers>
</system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true" />
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ChartImageHandler" />
      <add name="ChartImageHandler" preCondition="integratedMode" verb="GET,HEAD,POST" path="ChartImg.axd" type="System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartHttpHandler, System.Web.DataVisualization, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" />
    </handlers>
  </system.webServer>
```

Plus I had to add this on appSettings

```
<appSettings>
<add key="ChartImageHandler" value="storage=file;timeout=20;dir=c:\Temp\;" />
</appSettings>
```

Answer (score 0):

I intermittently get this error on our Windows 2003 server. I applied the web.config code from Michael's solution, but it still falls over occasionally. This is how I fix it:

Whilst remote desktopped on the Windows 2003 Server, I launched the website locally via `http://localhost/websitename`

The site works locally, and starts working fine everywhere else. No idea why!